# Input text very small when hovering on autofill suggestion

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, autofill

In Google Chrome on MacOS (Version 75.0.3770.142) when I hover over an autofill suggestion the font size in the input becomes very small (also the font family changes) but after choosing the suggestion it goes back to the normal size.

What might be causing this behaviour?

[image: autofill suggestion hover small font size]

Comment: *What might be causing this behaviour?* Probably the plugin you're using for the autofill

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837713/8620333 .. there is some *new* default styles added by chrome for specific states (not easy to override)

Comment: @ZohirSalak, not a plugin, just the default Google Chrome behaviour.

Comment: Oh it's the auto fill for saved passwords and such, funnily enough i can't reproduce on `Windows Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (64-bit)`

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yeah, I tested that on Chrome on Windows and it looks fine. It only breaks on a mac. I suppose it is a bug in Chrome and I just have to wait for a fix. I tried applying some styles from the other question Temani Afif mentioned but it doesn't seem to affect the font size (border color works for example).

Comment: This bug has been annoying me for a few weeks now. My Chrome has updated twice since it started happening and it hasn't been fixed yet. Fingers crossed this is a bug and not a feature!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Chrome from changing font when autofilling username/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026043/how-to-prevent-chrome-from-changing-font-when-autofilling-username-password)

Comment: @ThibaudColas It is not a duplicate because this issue happens only on a Mac and the linked issue happens only on Windows.

Comment: @KubaSzymanowski as far as I’ve been able to test myself the issue happens identically regardless of operating system, overriding both font-family and font-size.

Comment: I must've been mistaken then. In my tests it only happened on a Mac. This actually may very well be a duplicate.

Comment: Does anybody know if there is already an issue filed on Chrome/Chromium? This annoys me as well since a while now.

Comment: the possible duplicate above's top answer points to a chromium CVE that likely caused this intentional change: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=916838

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS AutoComplete font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195620/css-autocomplete-font-size)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a solution:

```
input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {font-size: 16px}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I notice its not just the font size but font family as well.

Comment: this solution doesnt work anymore in latest versions of Chrome because of a security issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1035058

Answer (score 3):

Here is working solution that worked for me in 2021 for Chrome not to change font size on autocomplete suggest hover:

```css
input#email {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
}

input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
      color: red;
      font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<input id="email"></input>
```

Also I noticed that for some reason `display: flex` conflicts with that code, take a look:

```css
input#email {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
      color: red;
      font-size: 2rem; 
}
```

```html
<input id="email"></input>
```

Comment: No longer working for me on macOS Chrome Version 95.

Answer (score 0):

input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:hover, input:-webkit-autofill:focus { 
 // put your old style here
}